# Computed Property not updating vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to pass an array of object from an async function in a .js file to a .Vue file where it gets it via a computed property. Unfortunately, it's not working. I would like to ask on how could I fix this

ModelList.js file

```
export default function(vm) {
  let modelList = []

  const getList = async () => {
    const data = await crud('model').list()
    modelList = data

 }

  getList()

  return {
   ...,
   tableList: modelList
  }
}
```

Table.Vue file

```
<template>...</template>
<script>
...
data: () => ({
  ...
}),
computed: {
  ...,
  tableList() {
    return this.table.tableList
  }
},
</script>
```

Model.vue file

```
<template>
  <Table v-bind="{tableList}" />
</template>

<script>
  import modelList from '../../meta/modelList'
  export default {
    ...,
  components: {
    Table
  },
  computed: {
    tableList () {
      return modelList
</script>
```

The flow is ModelList.js gets imported by Model.vue. Model.vue pass it to Table.vue

When I tried printing modelList in .js file, it shows the correct data. But when I try to print it in .Vue file, it shows null.

Comment: can  you show how you import this js file into .vue one ?

Comment: The .js file gets imported by Model.vue and the Model.vue file pass it to the .Vue file. I'll edit my post for clarity

Comment: modelList is function but you treat it like pure object. I don't see modelList() call.  So return modelList() from tableList in Model.vue

Comment: modelList is an array though

Comment: modelList is a function which will return object containing tableList.
export default function(vm) {....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make your array reactive by declaring it in `data`.

```js
data: () => ({
  modelList: []
}),
```

Next, update the reactive array after you receive your data.  Put the method in the component.

```js
methods: {
 async getList() => {
    this.modelList = await crud('model').list()
 }

}
```

You could also make your data reactive by declaring it in a `Vuex store`, or by using the composition API and the `setup()` method in Vue3 (or Vue2 as an addon).

Finally, reference the reactive array in your template.

```html
<template>
  <Table :tableList="modelList" />
</template>
```